# Next Auth Authentication fails

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using the latest NexAuth package for authentication. I am using an EmailProvider (passwordless system). To this effect, I have the following code

```js
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },

      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
```

I am facing a very weird issue. I am testing with two email domains ( gmail and outlook ).. Whenever I am sending the auth email to the gmail account, I can login to the system from the button in the Auth email.  However when I am clicking on email that was sent to the outlook address, I get the following error when the user clicks the sign in link from the email that was sent

```js
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'https://<myappName>vercel.app/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
```

If I [goto this site](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error) it does tell me that I need to define the NEXTAUTH_URL as one of the environment vars, which is what I have already done. Please see the below screenshot. Also if, the environment variable was not defined, then the login from Gmail address should not have worked.

[image: NEXTAUTH_URL is present]

Can you please help me out with this ? I am really not sure why its working for one and not for the other.